# Can't connect two nodes on same machine: cookie problem

Tags: erlang, distributed

Can anyone tell me how this is possible:

```
$ erl -sname n1 -setcoookie guitar
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

(n1@My-MacBook-Pro-2)1> erlang:get_cookie().
'TUUSVNDBMEWLOXSGZUAO'
```

Comment: Because you misspelled `-setcookie` as `-setcoookie`?

Comment: Jiminy Christmas!  Thanks for taking a look! Can you post your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to a syntax error; you've misspelled `-setcookie` as `-setcoookie`, with an extra `'o'`. With the correct spelling, you get the desired result:

```
$ erl -sname n1 -setcookie guitar
...
(n1@host)1> erlang:get_cookie().
guitar
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a poor soul.  My keyboard also thanks you!